# What is a parametrized function?

Tags: calculus, functions

I am readimg this article: [Stochastic Gradient Descent Tricks](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/192769/tricks-2012.pdf) and I would like some precisions:

> Each example $z$ is a pair $(x, y)$ composed of an arbitrary input $x$
>   and a scalar output $y$. We consider a loss function $\ell(\hat{y}, y)$
>   that measures the cost of predicting $\hat{y}$ when the actual answer
>   is $y$, and we choose a family $\mathcal{F}$ of functions $f_{w} (x)$
>   parametrized by a weight vector $w$

What is a parametrized $f_{w}(x)$ ?

My understanding would be that we construct the $\mathcal{F}$ family by considering all functions $f_{w}(x)$ generated by all possible vectors $w$.  And that parametrization is a way to restrict the scope of possible functions. Is this correct?

Eventually, can we say that a function $f_{w}(x)$ is like a function $f(w, x)$ with a fixed $w$ parameter?